# Error in exporting JAR file in Eclipse coded in java

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

Whenever I export my java file to JAR file in Eclipse, it is exported but with [an error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HpUib.png), `JAR export finish with warnings`. I am also unable to open that JAR file. There is the same problem with every program I made. All programs are running perfectly in Eclipse without any compilation error. Kindly guide.

[image: screeshot]

Comment: Seemingly there is a compilation error in ComboBoxExample.java

Comment: But during compilation and running, even not a single warning is displayed.

Comment: @trevorp caution, you have hidden the image in your edit

Comment: @Shahid these are *only* (compiler) warnings - details show so, like an unused import or variable - and should not be the cause for being unable to open he JAR. BTW what is meant with "unable to open that JAR file"? How are you trying to open it?

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger The image was not originally visible - it was just linked at the bottom with default description text. I simply moved the link up to a more logical place in the question. Your edit is the first one that made it visible.

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger I linked it near the top of the question "an error message".

Comment: ok, then I've not seen it, sorry - anyway image is visible now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply it means that the classes that you are try to export in jar have warnings.
I advise you to recompile the code and save all, then (if everything is right) try to export again the file. In extremis, close and restart Eclipse and try again.